# after noise reduction , output image colors are different

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time





def my_get_Gaussian2D_mask(msize, sigma=1):
    y, x = np.mgrid[-(msize // 2):(msize // 2) + 1,
           -(msize // 2):(msize // 2) + 1]

    gaus2D = 1 / (2 * np.pi * sigma**2) * \
             np.exp(-(( x**2 + y**2 )/(2 * sigma**2)))

    gaus2D /= np.sum(gaus2D)
    return gaus2D


def my_normalize(src):
    dst = src.copy()
    dst *= 255
    dst = np.clip(dst, 0, 255)
    return dst.astype(np.uint8)


def my_padding(src, pad_shape):
    (h, w) = src.shape
    (p_h, p_w) = pad_shape
    pad_img = np.zeros((h+2*p_h, w+2*p_w))
    pad_img[p_h:p_h+h, p_w:p_w+w] = src
    return pad_img


def my_filtering(src, mask):
    (h, w) = src.shape
    (m_h, m_w) = mask.shape
    pad_img = my_padding(src, (m_h//2, m_w//2))
    dst = np.zeros((h, w))
    for row in range(h):
        for col in range(w):
            val = np.sum(pad_img[row:row + m_h, col:col + m_w] * mask)
            dst[row, col] = val
    return dst


def add_gaus_noise(src, mean=0, sigma=0.1):
    #src : 0 ~ 255, dst : 0 ~ 1
    dst = src/255
    h, w, c = dst.shape
    noise = np.random.normal(mean, sigma, size=(h, w, c))
    dst += noise
    return my_normalize(dst)


def my_bilateral(src, msize, sigma, sigma_r):


    (h, w) = src.shape
    m_s = msize // 2
    img_pad = my_padding(src, pad_shape=(m_s, m_s))
    dst = np.zeros((h, w))

    y, x = np.mgrid[-m_s:m_s + 1, -m_s:m_s + 1]

    for i in range(h):
        print('\r%d / %d ...' %(i,h), end="")
        for j in range(w):
            k = y + i
            l = x + j
            mask = np.exp( -(((i - k)**2) / (2 * sigma**2)) -(((j-l)**2) / (2 * sigma**2)) ) * np.exp( -(((img_pad[i+m_s, j+m_s] - img_pad[k+m_s, l+m_s])**2)/(2*sigma_r**2)) )
            mask = mask/mask.sum()
            dst[i, j] = np.sum(img_pad[i:i + msize, j:j + msize] * mask)
    return dst


def my_median_filtering(src, msize):
    h, w = src.shape

    dst = np.zeros((h, w))
    for row in range(h):
        for col in range(w):
            r_start = np.clip(row - msize // 2, 0, h)
            r_end = np.clip(row + msize // 2, 0, h)

            c_start = np.clip(col - msize // 2, 0, w)
            c_end = np.clip(col + msize // 2, 0, w)
            mask = src[r_start:r_end, c_start:c_end]
            dst[row, col] = np.median(mask)


    return dst.astype(np.uint8)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    src = cv2.imread('canoe.png')
    np.random.seed(seed=100)

    noise_image = add_gaus_noise(src, mean=0, sigma=0.1)

    src_noise = noise_image.astype(np.float32)


    ##apple

    rgb_bilateral_dst = np.zeros_like(src)
    rgb_gaussian_dst = np.zeros_like(src)
    rgb_median_dst = np.zeros_like(src)

    for i in range(3):
        rgb_bilateral_dst[:, :, i] = my_bilateral(src_noise[:, :, i], msize=5, sigma=10, sigma_r=0.1)
        rgb_gaussian_dst[:, :, i] = my_filtering(src_noise[:, :, i], my_get_Gaussian2D_mask(5, sigma=1))
        rgb_median_dst[:, :, i] = my_median_filtering(src_noise[:, :, i], msize=5)

    
    yuv_img = cv2.cvtColor(src_noise, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)
    yuv_bilateral_dst = np.zeros_like(yuv_img)
    yuv_gaussian_dst = np.zeros_like(yuv_img)
    yuv_median_dst = np.zeros_like(yuv_img)

    for i in range(3):
        yuv_bilateral_dst[:, :, i] = my_bilateral(yuv_img[:, :, i], msize=5, sigma=10, sigma_r=0.1)
        yuv_gaussian_dst[:, :, i] = my_filtering(yuv_img[:, :, i], my_get_Gaussian2D_mask(5, sigma=1))
        yuv_median_dst[:, :, i] = my_median_filtering(yuv_img[:, :, i], msize=5)

    rgb_bilateral_dst = my_normalize(rgb_bilateral_dst)
    rgb_gaussian_dst = my_normalize(rgb_gaussian_dst)
    rgb_median_dst = my_normalize(rgb_median_dst)

    yuv_bilateral_dst = cv2.cvtColor(my_normalize(yuv_bilateral_dst), cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR)
    yuv_gaussian_dst = cv2.cvtColor(my_normalize(yuv_gaussian_dst), cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR)
    yuv_median_dst = cv2.cvtColor(my_normalize(yuv_median_dst), cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR)

    #banana

    cv2.imshow('original.png', src)
    cv2.imshow('RGB bilateral', rgb_bilateral_dst)
    cv2.imshow('RGB gaussian', rgb_gaussian_dst)
    cv2.imshow('RGB median', rgb_median_dst)



    cv2.imshow('YUV bilateral', cv2.cvtColor(yuv_bilateral_dst, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR))
    cv2.imshow('YUV gaussian', cv2.cvtColor(yuv_gaussian_dst, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR))
    cv2.imshow('YUV median', cv2.cvtColor(yuv_median_dst, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR))

    cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The image being printed should not be much different from the original, but it comes out strangely.
From comment app to banana, I wrote the code.
I think it's wrong because the color of the input image and the color of the output image don't match.
The other functions above the if function are well-completed codes without problems.
I would appreciate your help within the code I wrote.

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSCM6.jpg)

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JqDk.png)

Comment: You display 6 images in your code, which one is different? Please remove all the parts of the code that don't contribute to understanding the problem. Read "[mre]", where it's plained how to do this. For example, if all three filters have the same issue, you can just post the code for one filter here, learn what is wrong about it, and then see if that same fix also fixes your other filters. There's no need to post all three at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for the changing colors is related to arithmetic overflow.

The OpenCV valid pixel range of `uint8` dtype is [0, 255].
The OpenCV valid pixel range of `float32` dtype is [0, 1].

We better convert the input to `float32` and range [0, 1] at the beginning, apply the filters, and convert back to `uint8` in range [0, 255] at the end.

The method `my_normalize` scale by 255 and convert to `uint8` - we have to make sure that the input image to `my_normalize` is `float32` (or `float64`) in range [0, 1].

There is also a case when YUV to BGR conversion is performed twice.

---

Updated code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

def my_get_Gaussian2D_mask(msize, sigma=1):
    y, x = np.mgrid[-(msize // 2):(msize // 2) + 1,
           -(msize // 2):(msize // 2) + 1]

    gaus2D = 1 / (2 * np.pi * sigma**2) * \
             np.exp(-(( x**2 + y**2 )/(2 * sigma**2)))

    gaus2D /= np.sum(gaus2D)
    return gaus2D


def my_normalize(src):
    dst = src.copy()
    dst *= 255
    dst = np.clip(dst, 0, 255)
    return dst.astype(np.uint8)


def my_padding(src, pad_shape):
    (h, w) = src.shape
    (p_h, p_w) = pad_shape
    pad_img = np.zeros((h+2*p_h, w+2*p_w))
    pad_img[p_h:p_h+h, p_w:p_w+w] = src
    return pad_img


def my_filtering(src, mask):
    (h, w) = src.shape
    (m_h, m_w) = mask.shape
    pad_img = my_padding(src, (m_h//2, m_w//2))
    dst = np.zeros((h, w))
    for row in range(h):
        for col in range(w):
            val = np.sum(pad_img[row:row + m_h, col:col + m_w] * mask)
            dst[row, col] = val
    return dst


def add_gaus_noise(src, mean=0, sigma=0.1):
    #src : 0 ~ 255, dst : 0 ~ 1
    dst = src/255
    h, w, c = dst.shape
    noise = np.random.normal(mean, sigma, size=(h, w, c))
    dst += noise
    return my_normalize(dst)



def my_bilateral(src, msize, sigma, sigma_r):
    (h, w) = src.shape
    m_s = msize // 2
    img_pad = my_padding(src, pad_shape=(m_s, m_s))
    dst = np.zeros((h, w))

    y, x = np.mgrid[-m_s:m_s + 1, -m_s:m_s + 1]

    for i in range(h):
        print('\r%d / %d ...' %(i,h), end="")
        for j in range(w):
            k = y + i
            l = x + j
            mask = np.exp( -(((i - k)**2) / (2 * sigma**2)) -(((j-l)**2) / (2 * sigma**2)) ) * np.exp( -(((img_pad[i+m_s, j+m_s] - img_pad[k+m_s, l+m_s])**2)/(2*sigma_r**2)) )
            mask = mask/mask.sum()
            dst[i, j] = np.sum(img_pad[i:i + msize, j:j + msize] * mask)
    return dst


def my_median_filtering(src, msize):
    h, w = src.shape

    dst = np.zeros((h, w))
    for row in range(h):
        for col in range(w):
            r_start = np.clip(row - msize // 2, 0, h)
            r_end = np.clip(row + msize // 2, 0, h)

            c_start = np.clip(col - msize // 2, 0, w)
            c_end = np.clip(col + msize // 2, 0, w)
            mask = src[r_start:r_end, c_start:c_end]
            dst[row, col] = np.median(mask)


    #return dst.astype(np.uint8)
    return dst.astype(np.float32)  # Convert to type float32 (assume range is still range of float32 [0, 1]).


if __name__ == '__main__':
    src = cv2.imread('canoe.png')

    np.random.seed(seed=100)

    noise_image = add_gaus_noise(src, mean=0, sigma=0.1)  # Pass src as uint8 because add_gaus_noise assumes range [0, 255].

    src_noise = noise_image.astype(np.float32) / 255  # Convert src_noise from uint8 range [0, 255] to float32 valid range [0, 1]
    
    src = src.astype(np.float32) / 255  # Convert src from uint8 range [0, 255] to float32 valid range [0, 1]


    ##apple

    rgb_bilateral_dst = np.zeros_like(src)
    rgb_gaussian_dst = np.zeros_like(src)
    rgb_median_dst = np.zeros_like(src)

    for i in range(3):
        rgb_bilateral_dst[:, :, i] = my_bilateral(src_noise[:, :, i], msize=5, sigma=10, sigma_r=0.1)
        rgb_gaussian_dst[:, :, i] = my_filtering(src_noise[:, :, i], my_get_Gaussian2D_mask(5, sigma=1))
        rgb_median_dst[:, :, i] = my_median_filtering(src_noise[:, :, i], msize=5)
   
    yuv_img = cv2.cvtColor(src_noise, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)
    yuv_bilateral_dst = np.zeros_like(yuv_img)
    yuv_gaussian_dst = np.zeros_like(yuv_img)
    yuv_median_dst = np.zeros_like(yuv_img)

    for i in range(3):
        yuv_bilateral_dst[:, :, i] = my_bilateral(yuv_img[:, :, i], msize=5, sigma=10, sigma_r=0.1)
        yuv_gaussian_dst[:, :, i] = my_filtering(yuv_img[:, :, i], my_get_Gaussian2D_mask(5, sigma=1))
        yuv_median_dst[:, :, i] = my_median_filtering(yuv_img[:, :, i], msize=5)

    rgb_bilateral_dst = my_normalize(rgb_bilateral_dst)
    rgb_gaussian_dst = my_normalize(rgb_gaussian_dst)
    rgb_median_dst = my_normalize(rgb_median_dst)

    cv2.imshow('rgb_bilateral_dst', rgb_bilateral_dst)
    cv2.imshow('rgb_gaussian_dst', rgb_gaussian_dst)
    cv2.imshow('rgb_median_dst', rgb_median_dst)


    yuv_bilateral_dst = cv2.cvtColor(my_normalize(yuv_bilateral_dst), cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR)
    yuv_gaussian_dst = cv2.cvtColor(my_normalize(yuv_gaussian_dst), cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR)
    yuv_median_dst = cv2.cvtColor(my_normalize(yuv_median_dst), cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR)

    #banana

    cv2.imshow('original.png', src)
    cv2.imshow('RGB bilateral', rgb_bilateral_dst)
    cv2.imshow('RGB gaussian', rgb_gaussian_dst)
    cv2.imshow('RGB median', rgb_median_dst)


    # Avoid converting twice from YUV to BRG
    #cv2.imshow('YUV bilateral', cv2.cvtColor(yuv_bilateral_dst, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR))
    #cv2.imshow('YUV gaussian', cv2.cvtColor(yuv_gaussian_dst, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR))
    #cv2.imshow('YUV median', cv2.cvtColor(yuv_median_dst, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR))
    cv2.imshow('YUV bilateral', yuv_bilateral_dst)
    cv2.imshow('YUV gaussian', yuv_gaussian_dst)
    cv2.imshow('YUV median', yuv_median_dst)


    cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Output images (screenshot):

[image]

Comment: i really appreciate your kind answer.  i understood well. i will study hard from your answer.!

Comment: @learningmonkey Do you know how to mark an answer as an "accepted answer"?